# Is there any SFTP or SSH library for Go?

Tags: go, sftp

I can't seem to find any... it's a bit sad for a language positioned as networking-oriented one.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/taruti/ssh.go/src

Comment: I don't think an implicit conclusion should be part of the question.

Comment: Please don't post a question here if you can find the answer with google: http://www.google.com/search?q=golang+ssh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After sometime in exp/ssh, the official ssh package now resides in the crypto/ssh subrepo: http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=crypto#hg%2Fssh

Answer (score 1):

I know Caspar has already posted the link contained, but here is the list of community contributed packages:

http://godashboard.appspot.com/package

For completeness here are the official packages:

http://golang.org/pkg/

Also, since it is a VERY new language I don't feel too bad in saying, if it needs doing, I'm sure they would be happy for your contributions. (I try not to say "submit a patch" when we are talk about old languages/modules, however a new language is an exception)

Comment: Thanks downvoter, over two years later, I'm sure there is a better answer by now. Glad you got that one in aren't you?